# MVC Razor Form with multiple tick boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

Hi guys I got a view where a user can create a new skill to add to a database but I need to be able to use multiple levels. The user chooses a skill thats already in the database via a drop down list and then they select the tick boxes one by one according to what skill level belongs to that skill. So there will be 10 boxes for levels 1 to 10. This will then be added to a Skill Level database. Only the skill ID from Skill table and then each of the selected levels will be added to the database.

Anyone got any idea on how to implement this in a controller? I need the skill name to go to a skills table and the levels to a levels table where there is a foreign key to link the tables.

Im not sure what code you need but I will be using LINQ and vewmodels.

Thanks

EDIT: Updated the question as it did not seem clear.

Comment: if the skill or boxes will be autogenrated you should focus on client side to auto generate the boxes

Comment: I dont think I need to have them autogenerated. All skill levels will be from 1 to 10 its just different skills will have different range of levels.

Comment: yep so you need to controll that i would use ajax

Comment: any idea on how to do the ajax for that? would the ajax find the selected boxes and then send them to the controller?

Comment: it should be when user types the skill he has like java you have a selectbox/dropdowvnlist as user clicks or starts to select something from the dropdownlist is should update the options in the list based on the ajax call

Comment: I think your misunderstanding me. I dont want user to update any options. I want user to choose a skill from a list and then choose levels from tick boxes. then press a button and it adds the skill id and the levels into thier own database table.

Comment: but you do update the tick boxes based on skill??

Comment: No I dont. The check boxes are not ticked when the user loads the page, they choose a skill thats already in the database and then they select the tick boxes one by one according to what skill level belongs to that skill. This will then be added to a Skill Level database. Only the skill ID from Skill table and then each of the selected levels will be added to the database. I will update the question in case anyone else gets confused. There is no updating of anything. Im simply choosing what levels I want to add to the database out of 10 tick boxes.